# Unable to use Huion pencil for drawing

Tags: grease-pencil

I wanted to try 2D animation with my Huion device, but nothing can be drawn with the *Grease Pencil* option. In any other program like Photoshop, the pen works fine. The mouse pointer follows the pen, but it just doesn't draw anything. Also, the buttons on my pen work fine, but all I can do is move the camera. Of course, I'm in drawing mode. I also tried disabling Windows Ink in the Huion driver program. I found that it works at first, but only with a very small and short line that is almost unrecognizable (picture 2).

[image: Setting]

The only lines I could draw with the pencil:

[image: The only lines I could do with the pencil]

Comment: How did you make the lines you did?

Comment: I tried to draw with the huion pencil, those lines were the only ones I could do

Comment: I'm not sure about yours, but mine needs a lot of pressure to work. If you cannot get it to draw anything else, try fiddling around with preferences